# Are there any generic version of Array.newInstance?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I noticed that in Java `Array.newInstance()` returns `Object`, rather than `T[]`. It is understandable as this method was introduced before Java supports generic types.

However it is a surprise that there are no equivalent generic version of this. Java 7's `Arrays.copyOf` is not the same - it copies the content of the parameter, rather than creating a new dummy array (with all null objects inside).

Since implementation of this seems trivial, are there any reason not adding it into the JRE? or I just cannot find one?

**UPDATE**

It seems I shall provide my own "trivial" implementation to stop misunderstand of the question.

```
class MyArrayUtil {
    //Generic version for classes
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T[] newArrayOf(T[] t, int len){
        return (T[]) Array.newInstance(t.getClass().getComponentType(), len);
    }
    //For array of int
    public static int[] newArrayOf(int[] t, int len){
        return new int[len];
    }
    //For other primitive types...
}
```

I am not posting this code as an answer because it is not the answer of the question. The question is for reason and/or existing code, not how to implement.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code to make it similar to `Arrays.copyOf`, and the advantage is the programmer can simply change the type of the parameter to adjust the code for another type. Also I eliminated the use of `Array.newInstance` for primitive types.

Comment: No, it's impossible to implement this in a compile-time type safe fashion. For example, you can't create a new instance of a: `List<T>[]`. The compiler will never know what the type of `T` is, and so it can't guarantee that client code is safe.

Comment: Since `Arrays.copyOf` can do the job there are no obvious reason you cannot.

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf` determines the concrete type from the array to be copied.

Comment: So that's fine to have a similar `Arrays.newInstanceOf` that use a concrete type to provide type information, and as what I said in the question, that implementation is trivial.

Comment: Sort of a chicken in the egg problem with your method. In order to create an array I have to have already instantiated an array of the given type.  At that point I can just new one up my self. Your method offers no benefit over the existing.

Comment: Try: <T> T[] newInstance(Class<T> clazz, int length)  I'm on my phone so can't test. Take a look at http://www.AngelikaLanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html also

Comment: @Kyle You are right if I have a method like yours it can be more useful. However that does not mean mine has no way to use. Suppose you just want to write generic code that re-arrange (double the side, suffling it, etc) an existing array.

Comment: fwiw, Guava provides [just such a method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArrays.html#newArray%28java.lang.Class,+int%29).

Comment: @yshavit You are getting the most close to the answer... Can you go on and post your answer? Anyway Guava's arrays seems do not support primitive types.

Comment: @yshavit Also I found the answer you have just deleted makes some sense on reasoning. Can you restore it and add the Guava reference and discuss it? it seems like an acceptable answer.

Comment: Why not just use `Arrays.copyOfRange (t, t.length, t.length + len)` ?

Comment: @Jules Because it require you to have an existing instance in hand, but `newInstance` does not require anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guava provides [just such a function](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArrays.html#newArray-java.lang.Class-int-). It's not the first time Guava (or Apache Commons) provided a commonly-used helper that the JDK doesn't have, for whatever reason.

You may know this, but some background for the googler who stumbles upon this in the future: The reason the signature can't be made generic is that the method `Array.newInstance` [returned `Object` in Java 1.4](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int)), so for backwards compatibility, the raw version of the method should also return `Object`. If it had been generified as:

```
<T> T[] newInstance(Class<T> componentType, int length)
```

...then the return type would be `Object[]`, not `Object`. This would break backwards compatibility, which the Java designers have always tried very hard not to do.

The `Arrays.copyOf` methods only came in with Java 1.6, and thus didn't have to worry about backwards compatibility.

Comment: Now I think I understand why it is not makes much sense to have `newArray` supports primitive types. If you want to create a new array with types that are not generic type parameter, you can simply use `new XYZ[]`. If it is not the case you have to use class type, and only in this case the `newArray` facility is being useful.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if you require a similar parameter/field in your method signature/class definition.

Comment: @EarthEngine Also, it does work for primitive types, since `int.class` exists (and similarly for the other primitives). See http://ideone.com/aTVbJx for an example.

Comment: I know that is possible. But it only makes sense if you have a `Class<?>` instance at runtime. And in this case your code is explicitly uses reflection, not just generic.

Comment: Since changing the erased return type from `Object` to `Object[]` is a narrowing, it should at least in theory be binary-compatible.

Answer (score 4):

No, you need to pass the concrete type as a parameter one way or the other. As you mentioned, `Arrays.copyOf` shows this in action.

```
Class<T> type = determinteTheTypeSomehow();
return (T[]) Array.newInstance(type, length);
```

Comment: `Array.newInstance` require a `Class<?>`, as `Arrays.copyOf` requires `T[]`, so they do require additional parameter rather than a type parameter. I am just wondering why we cannot have an `Arrays.newInstance` that accepts `Class<T>` or `T[]` (as a template only; content inside is ignored).

Comment: yes i understand, but you are trying to bend the api to your needs which will never work ;) i admit this can be frustrating however that is the way it is.

Comment: When I write generic types i often pass in the concrete parameter type as an argument to the constructor for this (and other) purposes.

Answer (score 3):

The basic reason that `Array.newInstance()` cannot be declared like `<T> T[] newInstance(Class<T> class, int size)` is because it can be used to create arrays of primitives. So for example, if you pass in `int.class`, which has type `Class<Integer>`, then from the declaration you would expect it to return an `Integer[]` object. However, the function actually returns an `int[]` object, which is not a subtype of `Integer[]`, so it has the wrong type.

Sure, they *could* add an additional method like `newReferenceArrayInstance()` that prohibits primitive types (e.g. throws an exception when passed a primitive type) and thus can safely be declared to return `T[]`. However, that seems like adding a completely redundant method solely for avoiding an unchecked cast.